# Adding marker to google map in Ionic Application

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

I've been following this helpful tutorial - https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/.

Everything works great. However, this example prompts the user to add a marker to the google map by clicking on a button. I want the marker to be automatically added after the map loads in the view.

However, I'm receiving the error `cannot read propery of getCentre of undefined`
I'm quite sure that is telling me that it is attempting to add the marker before the map is loaded. Below is the code in my page TypeScript file:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as $ from "jquery";
import Shuffle from 'shufflejs';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-locator',
  templateUrl: 'locator.html'
})
export class LocatorPage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public geolocation: Geolocation) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // Load the google map
    this.loadMap();
  }

  // Function to add marker at current location
  addMarker(){

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: this.map.getCenter()
    });

    let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";

    this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

  }

  addInfoWindow(marker, content){

    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
      infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
  }

  // Function for loading the google map and getting geolocation coords
  loadMap(){

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    //automatically place marker at current location
    this.addMarker();    
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Like a trigger that fires after the map has finished loading? I can't seem to find an Ionic lifecycle event that I can run a hook from. Note that I am trying to run the `this.addMarker()` function after `loadMap()` has completed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call add marker just below `this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);`

like

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
this.addMarker();
```

or you can pass `map` to the map function as an argument

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
this.addMarker(this.map);
```

and your `addMarker` function

```
addMarker(map:any){

let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: map.getCenter()
});

let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";

this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);



}
```

Comment: Works like a treat! Thanks for your solution.